# getElementById sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8

I am working on a small Windows 8 application and I have this really annoying problem. First of all here is the HTML:

```
<h2 id="name" class="article-title win-type-ellipsis" data-win-bind="textContent: title"></h2>
<h4 id="price" class="article-subtitle" data-win-bind="textContent: price"></h4>
```

And here is the JavaScript:

```
order.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    Data.add(document.getElementById("price").innerText);
    var name = document.getElementById("name").innerText;
    var msg = Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(name + " added.");
    msg.showAsync();
});
```

The JavaScript works normally when getting the "price" element but for some reason decides not to work when getting the "name" element, I only get the message " added.".

There is no other element with the ID "name" and I am completely lost at why this doesn't work.

EDIT: There seems to be some confusion as to why both the HTML tags are empty in the code that I have provided. I bind the text from another JavaScript file and all that is working because when I run the application, there is text in those tags, the only problem is that for some reason I am able to grab the `price` element, but not the `name` element.

Comment: There's no `.innerText` in your `name` element.

Comment: The text to the `price` and `name` element is added with the `data-win-bind` attribute. When I run the application the text needed is there, but as I explained only the first line of the function works, the second doesn't....

Comment: Alright, let me put it this way. If `getElementById` wasn't returning the element, then accessing the `.innerText` property of that `null` result would throw an error, and you wouldn't get your `" added."` message at all. Try doing `Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog((typeof name) + " added.");` and see if it gives you `"string added."`

Comment: Yeah, I am getting `"string added"`

Comment: Ok, that means the element is found and there's no `.innerText`. Perhaps the content is loading asynchronously? Or maybe there actually is a duplicate ID that you missed? Try changing the name of the ID in the HTML and JS.

Comment: I did use find to check if there is another element with the same ID and there wasn't, but somehow this worked. Thank you :)

Comment: You mean changing the name of the ID worked? That's strange. Glad you got it working.

Comment: It still confuses me how exactly win8 works with HTML and JS just because of problems like this one, but I got it working so that doesnt matter now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following HTML:

```
<h2 id="name" class="article-title win-type-ellipsis" data-win-bind="textContent: title"></h2>
<h4 id="price" class="article-subtitle" data-win-bind="textContent: price">0.00</h4>
```

Comment: I can't see what you have changed, except adding the `0.00` in the 'price' element and that will get overwritten once I run the application because of the `data-win-bind` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the inner text is the content between the html tags. Since you have no inner text, the message can't display any.

Comment: I explained why both tags are empty my comment on the question.